# Modal is hiding when the Prev/Next of jquery UI datepicker is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, uikit

I use the jQuery datepicker https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ and the UIkit framework https://getuikit.com/

I want to use the datepicker in my form, inside the modal window.

The problem is that the modal window is hiding after clicking the Prev/Next of jquery UI datepicker.

Below is my code.

[**Demo on jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Yiannistaos/03ss4u43/1/)

Thanks in advance.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $("#from_date").datepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
    beforeShow: function(textbox, instance) {
      $('#ui-datepicker-div').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: -20,
        left: 5
      });
      $('#checkin_container').append($('#ui-datepicker-div'));
      $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.35/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.35/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.35/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<a class="uk-button uk-button-default" href="#modal-full" uk-toggle>Open</a>

<div id="modal-full" class="uk-modal-full" uk-modal>
  <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
    <button class="uk-modal-close-full uk-close-large" type="button" uk-close></button>
    <div class="uk-padding-large">
      <h1>Headline</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <div id="checkin_container" class="uk-width-1-2@s uk-margin-medium-bottom uk-text-left">
        <label class="uk-form-label" for="from_date">Check In</label>
        <div class="uk-form-controls uk-margin-small-top">

          <input type="text" placeholder="Check In" name="from_date" onfocus="blur();" id="from_date" autocomplete="off" class="uk-input yt-date">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

// Prevent DOM bubbling and it should be fine.

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Corrected Demo on jsfiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Yiannistaos/03ss4u43/42/